# Creating Docker containers from Airflow where Airflow itself is in a container (because of Windows 10). What am I missing?

Tags: python, docker, airflow

I have a simple example python script that I want Airflow to run on a scheduled basis. I can create the container for Airflow and successfully install the Docker server in this container. I can access the CLI and "docker run" the example's container manually and it works. When I try it from the localhost admin it just says "running" forever. Checking "docker ps" in the CLI shows that it hasn't launched a container. I'm sure I've missed something simple as there isn't a lot here to complicate things. Help please!?

Here is the python script:

```
import time as ti

def main():
    print('TEST')
    ti.sleep(120)
    print('COMPLETE')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and the Dockerfile to build it:

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /code

ENV PATH "$PATH:/code"

COPY docker_test.py .

CMD ["python", "docker_test.py"]
```

To create the Airflow Container I use this Dockerfile:

```
# Adds Docker to puckel image
FROM puckel/docker-airflow

# Adds DAG folder to the PATH
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/home/python_modules:/usr/local/airflow/dags"

# Install the optional packages
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
USER root
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Install docker inside the webserver container
RUN curl -ssl https://get.docker.com/ | sh
ENV SHARE_DIR /usr/local/share
```

requirements.txt contains docker and the docker run command is:

```
docker run --restart always --name airflow_container --privileged -d -p 8080:8080 -v C:/Users/myprojectfolders/shared_volumes/dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags -v //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock mydockerlogin/airflow:2 webserver
```

The final piece of the puzzle is the DAG file:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.docker_operator import DockerOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


default_args = {
    'owner': 'myname',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 10, 10),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=2)
}


dag = DAG(
    dag_id='docker_test',
    schedule_interval='*/5 * * * *',
    default_args=default_args    
)


task = DockerOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id='dockertask',
    container_name = 'dockertest',
    image='mydockerlogin/dockertest:2',
    auto_remove=False,
    docker_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock',
    command = ["python", "docker_test.py"] 
)
```

I have tried lots of variation around the command and entrypoint to no avail. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this is a bit embarrassing. I hadn't toggled the switch to "On" in the localhost admin.